# Do url rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have url given below

http://localhost/main20/pages/view.php?id=hello-world

and want it to be shown as

http://localhost/main20/hello-world

I know  its done using .htaccess and have found something here [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php) but its not fulfilling my requirement as my text "hello-world" will be changing on every request. Its something similar that wordpress does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: i have edited question to explain the difference between the two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found a solution my self here is the code and this http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html link solved my issue.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ pages/view.php?id=$1
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ pages/view.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** I am assuming that in http://localhost/main20/ will have index.php if not then create one. It will look a like something http://localhost/main20/index.php.

Now your `.htaccess` file would be something.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]
Options All -Indexes
```

In your `index.php`

```
<?php
define('WEBROOT','http://localhost/main20/');

//assuming your url is "http://localhost/main20/hello-wolrd"

$link=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  
$linkArr=explode("/",str_replace(WEBROOT,"","http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
/*
    print_r($linkArr);
    will output

    Array ( [0] => hello-wolrd ) 
*/

//now chech if $linkArr[0] is empty or not

if(!empty($linkArr[0])) 
{   
    include("pages/view.php?id".$linkArr[0]);
}
?>
```

Hope this help you.

[This](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/) is a good link for more information.

Comment: isn't there some way of achieving it through only .htaccess not involving any other file

Comment: where did you put .htaccess?

Comment: and make sure `mod_rewrite` is enable

Comment: same hierarchy of index.php file and module is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think this .htaccess should work for you. Put it in the same folder where index.php is

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ pages/view.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Ooops my bad, i didn't see that pages should be removed from link as well... Try it now

Comment: I tested this code on my localhost (i created folders main20 and pages) and it works for me. Here is my directory structure:
.:
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  298 јун 24 08:58 index.php
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 јун 24 08:45 pages

./pages:
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 24 јун 24 09:02 view.php

Comment: not for me found a solution here at point 4 http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html